# Cloudflare Edge cache TTL

Tags: caching, cloudflare

I've been testing Cloudflare, and I have Edge TTL set for 1 month for everything in the images folder. I'd like to see if this is set correctly, but in the Response Headers I don't see an EDGE TTL expiry. Is there any way for me to see when the cache will expire for an object in Cloudflare?

Here's the sample headers:

**Response Headers**

```
Request URL:https://cdn.mysite.com/content/testimage.jpg
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 
Remote Address:104.27.138.237:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
accept-ranges:bytes
cache-control:public, max-age=14400
cf-cache-status:HIT
cf-ray:37fa88117ff010f3-ORD
content-length:10512
content-type:image/jpeg
date:Mon, 17 Jul 2017 04:41:54 GMT
etag:"b9a9dca80fa816483b4df7e970639c98"
expires:Mon, 17 Jul 2017 08:41:54 GMT
last-modified:Mon, 17 Jul 2017 04:13:53 GMT
server:cloudflare-nginx
status:200
vary:Accept-Encoding
via:1.1 d784ab98a21beb476de2ec8d5824cf82.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id:MhQHg0-wZ_l7yEPeFkOvt7JXn4xuicRBpIVw2jlcy6Lt9KvukCrFcw==
x-amz-meta-s3cmd-attrs:atime:1499536352/ctime:1499536352/gid:1000/gname:sluser/mode:33204/mtime:1499536352/uid:1000/uname:sluser
x-cache:Miss from cloudfront
```

**Request Headers**

```
:authority:cdn.mysite.com
:method:GET
:path:/content/testimage.jpg
:scheme:https
accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8
cache-control:no-cache
cookie:__cfduid=df4ff5a2242e05fbc12499e832333f59c1500222401
pragma:no-cache
upgrade-insecure-requests:1
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 3):

Because EDGE TTL expiry are not reflected in the response header. They use this for their internal parameter to store files.
Visit this link for more detail 
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168376-What-does-edge-cache-expire-TTL-mean-